# How to draw a Field of View of Camera using Circle in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to paint an arc using WPF, but I somehow cannot figure out how to do this. I have searched a lot and came through Path property of WPF but i found that this is not good enough in my case.
My requirement is to show the Field of View of CCTV camera on a wpf.

There are following inputs from the user:
1. Center point of circle.
2. Radius of Circle.
3. Angle(0-360)

I want to allow user to draw a region of a circle or a full circle and can change the region by changing the angle and radius.
Note: 
1. Center is a fixed location on the canvas.
2. User can change the figure(region) dynamically.

Suppose user will provide angle 45 degree then the Circle will look like as in below image:
[image]

Comment: You are missing a piece of information.  From your picture, `Angle` determines the "width" of the slice, but I don't see where you provide the "Orientation" of the slice.  What determines if the FOV is facing, right, left, up, down, etc?

Comment: @BradleyUffner; actually at the center of the circle, there will be an image of camera which is acccording to diagram facing towards North-East direction.So the fov in this diagram is facing UP-Right and the angle will be anti-clock wise

Comment: I'm not going to figure out the trig right now but I'm pretty sure you could achieve it by combining a polygon and an ellipse.

Comment: An ellipse and a triangle mask will do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some quality time with my old Algebra text-book, I've got a fully working solution for you.

This uses the [WpfLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AgentOctal.WpfLib) Nuget package (Disclaimer: I am the author of this package) for `INotifyPropertyChanged` support, but you should easily be able to whatever change event system you want.  The full solution can be downloaded from [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/BradleyUffner/fieldofviewexample/src).

[image]

The XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="ViewingAngle.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewingAngle"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowVm}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <DockPanel Margin="4">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <TextBlock Margin="4,4,4,0" Text="{Binding Path=FieldOfView, StringFormat='Field of View: {0}'}" />
            <Slider
                Margin="4"
                Maximum="360"
                Minimum="0"
                TickFrequency="5"
                TickPlacement="Both"
                Value="{Binding Path=FieldOfView}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="4,4,4,0" Text="{Binding Path=TargetAngle, StringFormat='Target Angle: {0}'}" />
            <Slider
                Margin="4"
                Maximum="360"
                Minimum="0"
                TickFrequency="5"
                TickPlacement="Both"
                Value="{Binding Path=TargetAngle}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Viewbox Margin="4" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Canvas Width="500" Height="500">
                <Path
                    Fill="Blue"
                    Stroke="Blue"
                    StrokeThickness="1">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="250,250">
                                    <LineSegment Point="{Binding Path=StartPoint}" />
                                    <ArcSegment
                                        IsLargeArc="{Binding Path=IsLargeArc}"
                                        Point="{Binding Path=EndPoint}"
                                        Size="250,250"
                                        SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                                    <LineSegment Point="250,250" />
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry.Figures>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The View-Model:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using AgentOctal.WpfLib;

namespace ViewingAngle
{
    class MainWindowVm : ViewModel
    {
        private const int Radius = 250;
        private const int CenterX = 250;
        private const int CenterY = 250;


        public MainWindowVm()
        {
            FieldOfView = 45;
            TargetAngle = 90;
        }

        private int _fieldOfView;
        public int FieldOfView
        {
            get { return _fieldOfView; }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ref _fieldOfView, value);
                RecalculateArc();
            }
        }

        private int _targetAngle;
        public int TargetAngle
        {
            get { return _targetAngle; }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ref _targetAngle, value);
                RecalculateArc();
            }
        }

        private double GetRadians(int angle)
        {
            return angle * Math.PI / 180;
        }

        private void RecalculateArc()
        {
            var targetAngle = GetRadians(_targetAngle);
            var fieldOfView = GetRadians(_fieldOfView);
            var halfFieldOfView = fieldOfView / 2;

            var startAngle = targetAngle - halfFieldOfView;
            var endAngle = targetAngle + halfFieldOfView;
            double angleDiff = endAngle - startAngle;
            IsLargeArc = angleDiff >= Math.PI;

            StartPoint = new Point(CenterX + Radius * Math.Cos(startAngle), CenterY + Radius * Math.Sin(startAngle));
            EndPoint = new Point(CenterX + Radius * Math.Cos(endAngle), CenterY + Radius * Math.Sin(endAngle));
        }

        private Point _startPoint;
        public Point StartPoint
        {
            get { return _startPoint; }
            set { SetValue(ref _startPoint, value); }
        }

        private Point _endPoint;
        public Point EndPoint
        {
            get { return _endPoint; }
            set { SetValue(ref _endPoint, value); }
        }

        private bool _isLargeArc;
        public bool IsLargeArc
        {
            get { return _isLargeArc; }
            set { SetValue(ref _isLargeArc, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

All the magic happens in `RecalculateArc` which gets called whenever `TargetAngle` or `FieldOfView` are changed.  All the math has to happen in radians, so the first thing it does is convert the values.  It calculates new `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` values for the `ArcSegment` using some fairly simple algebra involving Sine and Cosine (though I still had to look the math up, because who remembers this stuff after high-school?).

In XAML, I placed some sliders bound to `TargetAngle`, and `FieldOfView` to allow you to control the angles.  It also contains the `Canvas` where the graphics are drawn, this is inside a `ViewBox`, just to make the indicator fill the available space.

The `Canvas` contains a `Path`, that is made up of one `PathFigure`.  The `PathFigure` starts at 250,250 (the center of the 500 x 500 `Canvas`), draws a `LineSegment` out to the arc's starting point, which is bound to `StartPoint`.  An `ArcSegment` is then added, that ends at `EndPoint`. `IsLargeArc` is just used to let the drawing system know which "half" of the arc to draw.  Another `LineSegment` that end back at the center is added to finish off the `PathFigure`.

Comment: @Bradley_Uffner Thank you!

Comment: Can you suggest me about the change if user wants to decrease the radius?

Comment: You can just add a `Radius` property, following the pattern of my properties. And add some bindings to replace the hard coded radius in my code. If you get stuck, let me know, and I'll update it after I get done with work today.

Comment: @ManishJain were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Sorry but when I try to change the radius, radius got changed but after that field of view not working properly...

Comment: I'm in the process of adding a bunch of features, including multiple FOVs, color, radius, and position.  It should be ready soon (I got caught up in this, and was having fun).

Comment: I've just updated the BitBucket repository with the new features.  Things got a little bit more complicated, but it shouldn't be too hard to follow if you understand the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @Bradley_Uffner Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it. Of course you'll need to put your own code to make it dynamic, but it is quite easy to control: in my example, I put two different figures so you will have two "field of view":

```
    <Ellipse Fill="Blue" Width="100" Height="100">
        <Ellipse.Clip>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="50,50" IsClosed="True">
                        <LineSegment Point="100,50"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="100,0"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="50,50" IsClosed="True">
                        <LineSegment Point="80,0"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="30,0"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Ellipse.Clip>
    </Ellipse>
```

Comment: I want to perform the same via angle and radius but not using three different points...

Comment: I think **cosinus** and **sinus** functions are made for that ^^. A simple converter or some databinding, and some _really easy_ maths functions would provide a stable component.